# Pytorch: Sparse Linear layer with costum connections

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, sparse-matrix, torch

I am building a large neural network which needs to have 500,000 input features and 20,000 features in the first hidden layer. In order to fit this massive model in memory i take advantage of the fact that I don't need all input features to be connected to all hidden features. In fact I only need one connection pr. input features with differing number of inputs going to the hidden layer. The first hidden layer is then connected to a dense layer. I.e I only need to train 500,000 weights in the input layer. In order to reduced memory consumption I want to ignore the remaining weights.

I am not using [pruning](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html) since, this requires initializing a `nn.Linear` object with the above dimensions - I have to little memory for this. I am therefore using the `sparselinear` package implemented by [hyeon95y](https://github.com/hyeon95y/SparseLinear). Using the `connectivity` argument to supply user defined connections. Using prior knowledge about my dataset I have created a LongTensor of the coordinates of non-zero values in my sparse layer `nnz`.

```
print(nnz.shape)
torch.Size([2, 536578])
```

```
print(nnz)
tensor([[     0,      1,      2,  ..., 536575, 536576, 536577],
        [     0,      0,      1,  ...,  20403,  20403,  20404]])
```

And I afterwards define by sparse layer as such:

```
input_layer = sl.SparseLinear(in_features = 536578,
                              out_features = 20405,
                              connectivity = nnz)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13877/4099142525.py in <module>
      1 snp_features = 536578
      2 gene_features = 20405
----> 3 input_layer = sl.SparseLinear(in_features = snp_features,
      4                               out_features = gene_features,
      5                               connectivity = gene_masks)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sparselinear/sparselinear.py in __init__(self, in_features, out_features, bias, sparsity, connectivity, small_world, dynamic, deltaT, Tend, alpha, max_size)
    269         values = torch.empty(nnz, device=coalesce_device)
    270 
--> 271         indices, values = torch_sparse.coalesce(indices, values, out_features, in_features)
    272 
    273 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/coalesce.py in coalesce(index, value, m, n, op)
     20     """
     21 
---> 22     storage = SparseStorage(row=index[0], col=index[1], value=value,
     23                             sparse_sizes=(m, n), is_sorted=False)
     24     storage = storage.coalesce(reduce=op)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_sparse/storage.py in __init__(self, row, rowptr, col, value, sparse_sizes, rowcount, colptr, colcount, csr2csc, csc2csr, is_sorted)
     63                 assert rowptr.numel() - 1 == M
     64             elif row is not None and row.numel() > 0:
---> 65                 assert int(row.max()) < M
     66 
     67         N: int = 0

AssertionError:
```

No, there is nothing after `AssertionError:`. This is how the error message is displayed. Does anyone know how I can use my coordinates in `nnz` to define a sparse input layer?

Comment: Just a guess into the blue: Have you tried updating the `SparseLinear` package? It seems the line of code that causes the trouble is now commented out [in the repository](https://github.com/hyeon95y/SparseLinear/blob/master/sparselinear/sparselinear.py#L352)